# Bind values of panda data.frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for a way to add rows from a subset together in a new variable.

Let us say we have the following dataset

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=('Body', 'ticketID'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["test1", 1], ["test2",1], ["test3",2],  ["test4",2]], columns=('Body', 'ticketID'))
df = df.append(df2)
```

And I create unique data.frames "df_temp" using the unique values of ticketID

```
uniqueIDs = df.ticketID.unique()
for u in uniqueIDs:
 df_temp = df2.loc[df['ticketID'] == u]
```

Now I would like to create one extra step that binds the body values of the seperate data.frame. So in case of the ticketID == 1 case -> "test1 test2" and in case of the ticketID == 2 case "test3 test4".

Any thoughts on how I can achieve this using the example above

Comment: Your question is unclear, please show the desired output. It sounds like you want `df.groupby('ticketID')['Body'].apply(' '.join)`

Comment: @EdChum, thanks. This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than loop over the df, you can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) on the ID column and [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply) a `join`:

```
In [82]:
df.groupby('ticketID')['Body'].apply(' '.join)

Out[82]:
ticketID
1.0    test1 test2
2.0    test3 test4
Name: Body, dtype: object
```